# Objects appear jagged in object mode

Tags: 3d-view

this started randomly happening during a blender session. The image is a default cube immediately after opening blender

[image]

All graphics drives are up to date: NVIDIA GeForece GTX 1080

I set everything back to factory settings, that did not work so downloaded blender again, no luck

any help would be great - thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok 1 minute after posting I found the answer. I will answer my own question rather than delete in case others have the same issue as it is a easy one to miss.

Camera clip start set too high at .0001 now reset to .01 and all fine.

[image]

If admin want to delete my answer no worries. Thanks